# preprocessing text with oracle sql

Tags: sql, regex, text-mining, data-cleaning

Again i will ask for your help in order to achieve some works with strings in an oracle database in order to make some preprocessing(before text mining).
So i have strings with that form in a varchar2 type table:
"#PROTESTOBR: Protestos em várias cidades brasileiras são destaque nos principais sites internacionais! O mundo começa a conhecer o Brasil de verdade! #vemprarua #vempraruarj #vempraruabrasil #ogiganteacordou #geracaoinvencivel  @J.Oliveira  Curta a Página Geração Invencível: http://www.facebook.com/GeracaoInvencive"

i want to recusirvely clean my strings cleaning them from # and urls. i'm investigating two ways:
1/ as i succeeded in extracting hashtags from my strings and exported them into another table i try to figure how to make a REPLACE like query taking as paramater the whole hashtags contained in my hashtags table. 
2/ just try to clean up my text with recursive CONNECT BY LEVEL clause. As i succeeded in extracting hahstags i try using my query with whom i succeeded in extracting my hashtags as a replace query:

```
SELECT replace(titre, (regexp_substr("my_string", '#\S+\s?'))) as wo#, d.l occurrence   FROM My_String_Table CROSS JOIN (SELECT LEVEL l FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL < 30) d WHERE regexp_like("my_string",'#\w+')    
AND d.l <=regexp_count("my_string",'#\w+');
```

The problem using this way is that it s returning me (as expected) as lines as the times the query encountered the pattern((regexp_substr("my_string", '#\S+\s?')). Results are very pretty good but, as you can guess i only want one result ^^
How can i do that? What s your advices ? How would have you proceed taking into account that i have not one string to deal with, of source, but approximatively 1 million. 
Thanks a lot for your advices!
Thanks bis because this query shown above was found thanks to stackoverflow examples.

Comment: You only want one result ? Can you be more specific ? Doesn't look like a regex problem unless the item is located somewhere anchorable.

Comment: mmmh... i have my string containing hashtags and i want to clean it from hashtags. As i already succeeded in creating an inventory of all hashtags in a table called hashtags i tried sthg like select replace("mystring",(select hashtags from hashtags-table)) from my string_table; but, of course it doesn't work (ORA-01427)

Comment: problem is that a string can contain up to ten different hashtags

Comment: Okay i propose a beginning of an answear:

Comment: Okay i propose a beginning of answear, using regex et replacing value paramater in the regex by a subquery, like this: "with stopwords as 
(select listagg(stopwords, '|') within group (order by stopwords) stopwords from t_portuguese_stopwords)
select src, regexp_replace(string,(select * from stopwords)) 
from my_strings_table ;" As you can imagine the result is not working: regular expression too long... how can i handle with that? Pliz help ^^